# Lock specific apps for each workspace in Ubuntu

Tags: launcher, workspaces

How can I make unity launcher remembers which apps are pinned to  it for each workspace and  automatically changes the Launcher when I switch between workspaces.

Knowing that I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a different Unity Launcher with different icons on each workspace?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/607640/how-to-get-a-different-unity-launcher-with-different-icons-on-each-workspace)

Answer (score 2):

[Unity LauncherSwitcher (LSwitcher)](https://launchpad.net/lswitcher) is a new tool which can be used to to control which apps should be pinned on the Launcher depending on the current workspace.

[image]

Available in  Ubuntu 15.04, 14.10 and 14.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/lswitcher
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lswitcher
```

[Watch this video](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-b5u92ajBtPc/VUDE6c-yUsI/AAAAAAAAWVQ/FybNz3YDDs8/s400/unity-launcherswitcher.png)

[source](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/04/organize-your-unity-launcher-based-on.html)