# How to have multiple Icons sets on different workspaces in Lubuntu?

Tags: icons, workspace-switcher

Is it possible to have multiple Workspaces with different icons? Like how the wallpaper works when you change between one another.

Comment: This looks like [fun](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/solved-different-icons-and-wallpapers-in-each-workspace-ubuntu-852686/). I've never tried it so I don't know but it does say solved and people seem inclined to agree. Give that a looksee.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean one workspace has Gnome icons and the next has Unity icons?

If so, I doubt that's possible because when your Linux boots up your desktop environment say Gnome, Gnome now "controls" the environment and how you interact with it, so if you moved to the next environment, your PC would need to turn off the Gnome environment and load up the LXDE environment, that means you'll have to wait to use it again.

We can't waste time, especially when you are working on a project.

If not, then you can try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607640/how-to-get-a-different-unity-launcher-with-different-icons-on-each-workspace), quite a lengthy but informative guide on changing icons.

Here is another [site](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/solved-different-icons-and-wallpapers-in-each-workspace-ubuntu-852686/) for your question.